# How to optimize Next.js images from an external url without Vercel Image Optimization

Tags: next.js, vercel, image-optimization

Is there any way to optimize Next.js images on the fly without using Vercel's Image Optimization with the `next/image` component?

Specifically for external URLs, not images I'm self-hosting.

I am using Vercel but close to exceeding the free image limit and it is $5 per 1000. I may greatly exceed this in the near future so I may need to turn off optimization altogether in the meantime.

I don't think it's recommended to run the app DNS through Cloudflare if I'm using serverless and edge functions.